# Print all properties of an App Engine Model

Tags: python, google-app-engine, properties, django-templates

I'm trying to find a way to easily loop through a Google App Engine (Python) Model and to print out each property and the property name.

This is how I'm trying it, and after some research I realize I can't next variables in each other. Is there a way to do this with filters or a way to return all of the values of the properties of a Model?

Thanks

```
templateargs = {'properties':MyModel.properties(), 'user1':MyModelObj, 'user2':MyModelObj}


{% for property in properties %}
    Property: {{property}}
    User1:  {{user1.{{property}}}}
    User2:  {{user2.{{property}}}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I realized the proper way to do this was with gettattr. I used a filter along the lines of:

```
@register.filter 
def mygetattr(obj, name): 
    return getattr(obj, name)
```

As suggested [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/7c12546c6942389b)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how [this `to_json` method](https://gist.github.com/881913) grabs all the property values on a Model instance, it should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
vars(user1)[property]
```

See [Built-in Functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions).html#vars for a short explanation of how `vars` returns a dictionary of the instance variables.