# Loop over GqlQuery Fields, App Engine, Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gqlquery

I want to output all attributes and values of the following GqlQuery:

```
benchmarks = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Benchmarks")
```

What's the easiest way to loop over the GqlQuery and output the names and values generically?

To be more precise, I DO NOT want to do this:

```
benchmarks = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Benchmarks")                           
        for b in benchmarks:
            self.response.out.write("<td>name:%s</td>" % b.name)
            self.response.out.write("<td>Id:%s</td>" % b.id)
```

But rather have all properties of a benchmark displayed, independent of their name.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print all properties of an App Engine Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754994/print-all-properties-of-an-app-engine-model)

Comment: Do you need to know all the properties that are in the datastore, or is it sufficient to loop over the properties in the current definition of your `Benchmarks` model?

Comment: @Wooble That depends if he just wants to iterate over model properties, or retrieve datastore column stats.

Comment: @Wobble: I would like to "dump" the datastore, basically output all instances with their model properties and their values.